# Aggregating length of time intervals and grouping to fixed time grid

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have some data consisting of shifts, logging the time periods taken as breaks during the shift.

```
start_ts                end_ts                  shift_id
2022-01-01T08:31:37Z    2022-01-01T08:58:37Z    1
2022-01-01T08:37:37Z    2022-01-01T09:03:37Z    2
2022-01-01T08:46:37Z    2022-01-01T08:48:37Z    3
```

I want to map this data to a 15-minute grid, counting how many seconds in total (not per shift) are spent on break during that interval. A solution would look like this:

```
start_time               end_time               total_break_seconds
2022-01-01T08:30:00Z    2022-01-01T08:45:00Z      1246
2022-01-01T08:45:00Z    2022-01-01T09:00:00Z      1837
2022-01-01T09:00:00Z    2022-01-01T09:15:00Z      217
```

I know this is a gaps-and-islands style problem, but I'm not sure how to combine this with the mapping to a time grid element. I've looked at using UNIX_SECONDS/time-to-epoch to get the 15-minute intervals, but can't make it out. I'll be working with pretty large tables so ideally I would do as much work as possible *before* expanding each time interval to the 15-minute grid, but all solutions welcome.

I'm working on BigQuery

Here's a reproducible example to start with:

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP("2022-01-01 08:31:37") AS start_ts,
    TIMESTAMP("2022-01-01 08:58:37") AS end_ts,
    1 as shift_id
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      TIMESTAMP("2022-01-01 08:37:37") AS start_ts,
      TIMESTAMP("2022-01-01 09:03:37") AS end_ts,
      2 as shift_id
  )
  UNION ALL (
    SELECT
      TIMESTAMP("2022-01-01 08:46:37") AS start_ts,
      TIMESTAMP("2022-01-01 08:48:37") AS end_ts,
      3 as shift_id
       )
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? (PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc)

Comment: Bigquery - edited to include that info

Comment: Sometimes you round up and sometimes down. I don't see the pattern.

Comment: If I do, that's a mistake @shawnt00 - which line is confusing?

Comment: It's not a gaps and islands problem nor does it have anything to do with mapping. I had initially misunderstood the goal because of those terms. My impression was that you wanted to associate a break with a certain 15-minute window rather than break each interval into segments across those boundaries.

Comment: feel free to edit @shawnt00, but both answers seemed to grok the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With below query:

```sql
WITH breaks AS (
  SELECT *,
         CASE
           -- for staring break (considering start_ts and end_ts are in same break)
           WHEN break <= start_ts AND end_ts < break + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE THEN TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_ts, start_ts, SECOND)
           WHEN break <= start_ts THEN 900 - TIMESTAMP_DIFF(start_ts, break, SECOND)
           -- for remaining breaks (considering full break + partial break)
           ELSE IF(DIV(diff, 900) > 0 AND break + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE < end_ts, 900, MOD(diff, 900))
         END AS elapsed
    FROM sample,
         UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
           TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(start_ts, HOUR), TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(end_ts, HOUR) + INTERVAL 1 HOUR, INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
         )) break,
         UNNEST([TIMESTAMP_DIFF(end_ts, break, SECOND)]) diff
   WHERE break + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE >= start_ts AND break < end_ts
)
SELECT break AS start_time, break + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE AS end_time, SUM(elapsed) total_break_seconds 
  FROM breaks
 GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

Output will be:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider below

```
with grid as (
  select start_time, timestamp_sub(timestamp_add(start_time, interval 15 minute), interval 1 second) end_time
  from (
    select max(end_ts) max_end,
      timestamp_trunc(min(start_ts), hour) min_start
    from your_table
  ), unnest(generate_timestamp_array(min_start, max_end, interval 15 minute)) start_time
), seconds as (
  select ts from your_table, 
  unnest(generate_timestamp_array(start_ts, timestamp_sub(end_ts, interval 1 second), interval 1 second)) ts # this is the line with fix
)
select start_time, end_time, count(*) total_break_seconds
from grid
join seconds
on ts between start_time and end_time
group by  start_time, end_time
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: How would this scale when the shift intervals get bigger? Seems like the `seconds` table is really big?

Comment: Also found a slight discrepancy with the correct result - as seen when compared with the other answer

Comment: you are right. see fix (respective line is marked as having fix). as of `seconds` becomes really big - i don't think this will be an issue - especially having specific context in your question - shifts, breaks, etc. :o) but, sure  - agree  - in generic case this might be an issue

Comment: sure - my context is like 1-3 years worth of data - but i didn't want to write that many shifts in the example!